# Easiest method/best tool to synchronize table index between multiple databases

Tags: postgresql, indexing

As the title mentions, I need to synchronize table indexes between multiple databases(that have identical structures). However, based on my research, most tools like DBeaver enterprise and Pgadmin only support the comparison of two databases/schemas at once. Are there any tools that support the comparison of multiple databases/schemas, or is there any query that can perform this action? I have searched and so far I have only found this [query](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-list-indexes/) that lists all indexes for a single database.

Alternatively, I thought that I should just query all indexes from each database and compare them manually, but there are too many schemas and tables in each database, so right now my last resort is to export the tables of indexes as CSV and write my own program to perform the comparisons... Is this a viable option?

Comment: You **can not** synchronize indexes. An index entry contains the actual storage location of the indexed column value in the actual table. While tables can have identical structures and identical content, the storage of data within them will not be the same. Thus an **index will can not be the same**.

Comment: Sorry, is my understanding not correct? Based on what I recall, indexes are additional search structures, so even if the data differ, wouldn't it be possible to create the same index if the tables have similar structures?

Comment: Your understanding in not correct, an index is not **an additional** search structure. It is specific to a single table and often to a single column in that table and only that table. A index aids *searching* value(s) within specific column(s) within the table the it is defined on. Index entries **identify physical location of a row within its table**. Even if 2 tables have identical structure and the exact same data the tuples (rows) will not be in the same location.  BTW you cannot directly access the index.